# How many Services should I have?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I have an app that checks GPS position and interacts with four websites.  I am thinking of using ASync tasks within a Service.  The result from each website does not depend on any other website.

As finding the location and interacting with each website will take a different amount of time, does this mean I should have five services?  Or should it all be combined into one service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the other 4 services after you get a GPS fix. You can create new instances of each AsyncTask running in parallel. I don't see the need for using a service. I use one httpClient object stored in an application class for all web requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need additional services. The problem here, as I understand, is that each HTTP call might take a long time to finish and that would slow down the whole process and that you will have too many ASynkTasks. Then, Google has already solved the problem for you.

Instead of using ASyncTasks you can use [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) and send all your requests to websites in parallel. That way, Volley will handle your requests in different threads and keep everything tidy. As a bonus it is [A LOT faster](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) than ASyncTask.